# How to fix problem with netplan configuration (ip address show) for Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: networking, 22.04, netplan

Using ubuntu 22.04 I tried to assign the two IP addresses `192.168.200.100` and `169.254.1.0` to the ethernet device `enx00e04c680202`. Following [this tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/netplan-network-configuration-tutorial-for-beginners) and [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/681220/netplan-generate-gateway4-has-been-deprecated-use-default-routes-instead) I created a file `/etc/netplan/01-network-config_home.yaml` with the following content:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enx00e04c680202:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.200.100/24
        - 169.254.1.100/24
      routes:
       - to: default
         via: 192.168.200.220
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 8.8.8.8   # Add your DNS server IP address
          - 8.8.4.4   # Add another DNS server IP address
```

and applied the changes using the command

```
sudo netplan apply
```

I checked the configuration with the command `ip address show dev enx00e04c680202`, but it seems only one address has been applied:

```
3: enx00e04c680202: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:68:02:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.200.100/24 brd 192.168.200.255 scope global noprefixroute enx00e04c680202
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

But the other configured address seems to be working! Even it does not show up with the command

```
ip address show dev enx00e04c680202
```

I am able to connect to a device with IP address 169.254.1.0 that is connected only to that ethernet adapter.

When I add an IP address to that adapter `enx00e04c680202` using the following command

```
sudo ip addr add 169.254.1.100/24 dev enx00e04c680202
```

then I see the following output of the command `ip address show dev enx00e04c680202`:

```
3: enx00e04c680202: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:68:02:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.200.100/24 brd 192.168.200.255 scope global noprefixroute enx00e04c680202
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 169.254.1.100/24 scope global enx00e04c680202
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

It shows the two IP addresses not only one. Maybe that is a bug with `ip address show`?

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in either `netplan` or `ip`..

Comment: But to understand correctly, it is actually working with both IP addresses, but address #2 just doesn't show on `ip address show` output, correct?

Comment: @ArturMeinild Yes that seems to be the case. Even the IP address shown is ONLY 192.168.200.100 I can connect to a device with an IP 169.254.1.0 that is connected ONLY on that ethernet adapter ...

Comment: Then maybe change the title - because the netplan is working, it's just not showing on `ip addr`. I still think it's a bug then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to statically assign the address `169.254.1.100/24`.  The `169.254.0.0/16` address space is reserved for IPv4 autoconfiguration. It appears NetworkManager is refusing to allow you to statically assign an IP address in this range.  You can enable use of an address in this range with the `link-local` directive, e.g.:

```
enx00e04c680202:
  addresses:
    - 192.168.200.100/24
  routes:
   - to: default
     via: 192.168.200.220
     metric: 200
  link-local: [ ipv4, ipv6 ]
```

See https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/stable/netplan-yaml/#properties-for-all-device-types for an explanation of `link-local`.