# How to fix automatic apply of netplan config after reboot not working?

Tags: networking, 22.04, netplan, ip

I am using ubuntu 22.04 and trying to apply the following netplan automatically at startup:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enx00e04c680202:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.200.100/24
        - 169.254.1.100/24
      routes:
       - to: default
         via: 192.168.200.220
         metric: 200
      routes:
       - to: default
         via: 169.254.1.220
         metric: 300
```

To do so I create a file `/etc/systemd/system/netplan-apply.service` with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Apply Netplan configuration on startup
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/netplan apply
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and started the service with the commands

```
sudo systemctl enable netplan-apply.service
sudo systemctl start netplan-apply.service
```

After bootup these setting have not been applied as the command `ip address show dev enx00e04c680202` shows:

```
3: enx00e04c680202: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:e0:4c:68:02:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Only after a while (a minute) or after I have been trying to connect to a device connected to this adapter this command `ip address show dev enx00e04c680202` showed:

```
3: enx00e04c680202: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:68:02:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.200.100/24 brd 192.168.200.255 scope global noprefixroute enx00e04c680202
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

My question: Is this also a bug (**), or does it take the system to apply the netplan configuration some time (a minute)? Or am I doing something wrong? How to make sure the netplan configuration is always applied after startup?

(**) The bug refers to the fact that although I specify two IP addresses for that adapter `enx00e04c680202` the command `ip address show dev enx00e04c680202` only shows one, see [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1498744/how-to-fix-problem-with-netplan-configuration-ip-address-show-for-ubuntu-22-04).

Answer (score 1):

netplan config is automatically applied at boot via the netplan generator `/lib/systemd/system-generators/netplan`, in the `netplan.io` package in releases up to Ubuntu 23.04 and in the `netplan-generator` package in Ubuntu 23.10 and later.  There is no need to create a custom systemd unit for applying netplan config.

It may take some time for the interface to be configured after boot; this is likely hardware-dependent.

Regarding your second IP interface not appearing, you are trying to statically assign the address `169.254.1.100/24`.  The `169.254.0.0/16` address space is reserved for IPv4 autoconfiguration; the network stack is likely refusing to allow you to statically assign an IP address in this range.  You can enable use of an address in this range with the `link-local` directive, e.g.:

```
enx00e04c680202:
  addresses:
    - 192.168.200.100/24
  routes:
   - to: default
     via: 192.168.200.220
     metric: 200
  link-local: [ ipv4, ipv6 ]
```

See https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/stable/netplan-yaml/#properties-for-all-device-types for an explanation of `link-local`.